# Font portability between platforms? Windows/Linux

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, windows, linux

If I first work in Windows environment then move to Linux, do I just copy all the fonts in the Windows system font folder into the Linux system font folder?

I'll be using xelatex and fontspec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

save the fonts in `/usr/local/share/fonts` and then run `sudo fc-cache -r`
If you have a lot of fonts then create the subdirectories `opentype` and `truetype` in the fonts directory. This makes it easier to find a specific font.